# Событие onclick срабатывает только по первому элементу в динамической разметке

Tags: javascript, битрикс

Я работаю на битрикс 1с и у меня произошла следующая проблема. Я хочу сделать чтобы функция срабатывала при нажатии на конкретный элемент. У меня срабатывает только на первом элементе.Как мне быть?

```
<? if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<? foreach ($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem) : ?>
    <?

            $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
            $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
            ?>
            <p class="news-item" onclick="Buy()" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
            
            <? if ($arItem["PROPERTIES"]["STOCK"]["VALUE"] == "Y") : ?>

                <div  id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>" class="card tag_red swiper-slide">
                <p class="news-item" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
                <? elseif ($arItem["PROPERTIES"]["DISCOUNT"]["VALUE"] == "Y") : ?>
                    <div class="card tag_blue swiper-slide ">
                    <? else : ?>
                        <div class="card swiper-slide ">
                        <? endif ?>
                        <div class="card__body">
                            <? if ($arItem["PROPERTIES"]["STOCK"]["VALUE"] == "Y") : ?>
                                <div class="card__tag">хит</div>
                            <? elseif ($arItem["PROPERTIES"]["DISCOUNT"]["VALUE"] == "Y") : ?>
                                <div class="card__tag">-25%</div>
                            <? else : ?>
                                <div class="card__tag"></div>
                            <? endif ?>
                            
                            <? $arFile = CFile::GetFileArray($arItem["PROPERTIES"]["PHOTO"]["VALUE"]); ?>
                            <input type="text" id="middle-label" placeholder="Введите количество">
<input type="hidden" id="element_id" value="<?=$arItem['ID']?>"><!-- Поле для хранения ID товара -->
<?print_r($arItem['ID'])?>
<button   class="button large expanded" >Купить</button>


                            <img class="card__img" src="<?=$arFile["SRC"]?>" alt="">
                            <div class="card__title"><?= $arItem["PROPERTIES"]["PRODUCTION"]["VALUE"]; ?></div>
                            <div class="card__text"><?=$arItem["PROPERTIES"]["DESCRIPTION"]["VALUE"]["TEXT"]?></div>
                            <div class="card__price-wrapper">
                                <div class="card__price"><?= $arItem["PROPERTIES"]["PRICE"]["VALUE"]; ?><span>₽</span></div>
                                <div class="card__amount"><?= $arItem["PROPERTIES"]["WEIGHT"]["VALUE"] / 1000; ?><span>кг</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card__cart-wrapper">
                            <button class="card__cart-btn" type="button" data-action="add_cart">
                                добавить в корзину
                            </button>
<div class="card__amount-choice">
                                <button class="card__amount-decrease card__amount-btn" type="button" data-action="amount_decr">
                                </button>
                                <span class="card__amount-num">1</span>
                                <button class="card__amount-increase card__amount-btn" type="button" data-action="amount_incr">
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                            </p>
                    <? endforeach ?>

                    
                        <script>
function Buy() {
    const kol = document.getElementById('middle-label').value;//Получаем количество из поле ввода
    const id = document.getElementById('element_id').value;//Получаем ID товара
    var formData = new FormData();//Создадим объект для передачи данных
    formData.append('id', id);//Добавим переменную с ID товара
    formData.append('kol', kol);//Добавим переменную с количеством товаров
    alert(id);
    //ajax
    var HttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();//Создадим объект для отправки AJAX запроса
    HttpRequest.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {//Проверка что результат отчета успешный (может быть 404 или другие)
            //alert('Товар добавлен в корзину');//Сообщение
            //document.getElementById('chart-value').innerText = this.response;//Записываем цифру в элемент корзины в верстке
        }
    };//Функция в которую возвращается ответ от сеовера
    HttpRequest.open("POST", '/personal/cart/', true);//Настройка запроса для отправки (второй параметр путь к PHP скрипту)
    HttpRequest.send(formData);//Отправка запроса на сервер
}
</script>
```

Comment: Атрибут `id` должен быть __уникальным__ на странице.

Comment: @u_mulder id кнопки?

Comment: __Любого__ элемента. `document.getElementById('element_id')` - как тут понять какой брать элемент? Первый? Пятый? Последний?

Comment: @u_mulder, спасибо)